# Finding the derivative with the limit definition

Tags: limits, derivatives

$f(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$ at $x = 9$. I plugged 9 in for all the places x showed up for in the limits definition and I end up with $$\frac{2(3 -\sqrt{9+h})}{3h \sqrt{9+h}}$$
I'm unsure of what to do here because I can't set h to 0!

Comment: You gotta wait until the end to plug in x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

$$3-\sqrt{9+h}=\frac{9-(9+h)}{3+\sqrt{9+h}}=\frac{-h}{3+\sqrt{9+h}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{2(3-\sqrt{9+h})}{3h\sqrt{9+h}}=\frac{-2h}{(3+\sqrt{9+h})(3h\sqrt{9+h})}=\frac{-2}{(3+\sqrt{9+h})(3\sqrt{9+h})}$$

now take the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what you should be taking the limit of as $h \rightarrow 0$ is $$\frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt{x+h}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}}{h}$$ And once you have taken the limit, THEN you can plug in $x=9$

Comment: Actually, what the OP wrote above is just fine...see hammood's answer for the way to proceed from there.

Comment: You can plug in x before taking the limit?

Comment: Sure. Do what the OP did, then apply hammood's hint.

Comment: Try this with $ln(x)$ at $x=-1$. The derivative is defined at $-1$

Comment: $\ln x$ is not even defined at $-1$, so its derivative surely is not. Perhaps you mean $\ln |x|$.